# converting array to custom list

Tags: c#

In my app I am writing data into a text file by converting a list into an array, later on I want to load it by converting it to the same list type and return it like that.

My code:

```
public abstract class PhoneBookCore
{
    protected string _group;

    public PhoneBookCore(string group)
    {
        this._group = group;
    }
}

public class Group : PhoneBookCore
{
    private List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>();

    public List<PhoneBookCore> elementsList { 
         get { return new List<PhoneBookCore>(elements); } 
    }

    public Group(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

class DataOptions
{
    public void Save(Group g)
    {
        string[] lines = g.elementsList.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();
        File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
    }

    public Group Load()
    {
        string[] buffer = File.ReadAllLines(path); // ----> How do I convert it back
                                                   //       to list of type group?

        return ;
    }
}
```

How do I convert it back to list of type group?

Comment: Why do you always create a new list in the `elementsList` property? Just return `elements`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I had to guess, I'd say to make the stored list read-only.

Comment: What is your question?  If it's just what's in the comment, you could make it clearer (and you only need two lines of code to illustrate...)

Comment: how do i convert it back to list of type group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe (assuming that you want to pass the whole line to the Group-constructor)

```
List<Group> allgroups = File.ReadLines(path)   
    .Select(l => new Group(l))
    .ToList();
```

Note that I've used `File.ReadLines` which returns a streaming `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string[]`, you can also read all into memory at once with `File.ReadAllLines`.

But why do you always create a new list in the `elementsList` property? Just return `elements`.

**Edit** If you want to create one group and set the `elementsList` from the lines, you need to provide the setter of the property first:

```
private List<PhoneBookCore> _elementsList = new List<PhoneBookCore>();
public List<PhoneBookCore> ElementsList
{ 
    get { return _elementsList; }
    set { _elementsList = value; }
}
```

Then you can initialize and set the group on this way:

```
Group g = new Group(path); // i have no idea
g.ElementsList = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => new PhoneBookCore(l))
    .ToList();

return g;
```

Comment: i want to return the list as type group

Comment: Then you need to provide a setter for the `elementsList` property. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to project each string item in your buffer list to a new PhoneBookCore instance.  Since you're already using LINQ extensions, the following should suffice:

```
elementsList = buffer.Select(s => new PhoneBookCore(s)).ToList();
```